# Process exited with status 127 after ddploying spring boot on heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, web, heroku

i have a spring boot app that runs locally on my machine without any problem but when I deploy it on Heroku, I get these errors:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

I use Intellij and i have done the necessary configurations to compile with Java 8.

the second error reads:

```
2023-07-19T12:15:09.744331+00:00 heroku[run.8115]: Awaiting client
2023-07-19T12:15:09.757393+00:00 heroku[run.8115]: Starting process with command `rdd-main`
2023-07-19T12:15:09.879225+00:00 heroku[run.8115]: State changed from starting to up
2023-07-19T12:15:13.029112+00:00 heroku[run.8115]: Process exited with status 127
2023-07-19T12:15:13.070949+00:00 heroku[run.8115]: State changed from up to complete
```

POM.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.rdd</groupId>
    <artifactId>RDD</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RDD-GHS_Accra</name>
    <description>RDD</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
          </dependency>

        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have read a lot of articles but none has any direct fix.
Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Can you please show your pom.xml/build.gradle?

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @dan1stisonstrike, pom.xml has been added, thanks.

Comment: @Turing85 not sure i understand your question

Comment: Try adding `<java.version>1.8</java.version>` to the `<properties>` section of your pom.xml. Does that change anything?

Comment: Read [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion) article, might help